# Fatal error: Uncaught MercadoPagoException: collector doesn't have me2 active

Tags: php, javascript

estoy tratando de enviar un pago pero estoy teniendo problemas me manda **Fatal error: Uncaught MercadoPagoException: collector doesn't have me2** . Anteriormente estaba trabajando correctamente pero justo nos marco esto. Alguna idea de por donde va? o si Mercado Pago hizo algún ajuste en las cuentas?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Tienes activado [Mercado Envíos](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/envios)?

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida. Llevamos un rato trabajando con este proyecto y con esta cuenta, ya hemos generados pedidos con envío, es curioso que de repente se hubiera apagado. Deberíamos tenerlo activo.

Comment: Sea como sea deberías revisar si está activado. Nada es perfecto y las cosas se pueden apagar, desactivar por fallos, por actualizaciones, etc.

Comment: Ya estoy revisando. Cuando entro a la cuenta de mercado pago en https://www.mercadopago.com.mx/settings/my-business en el menú de la izquierda ->Configuración -> Pestaña Negocio- >Mercado Envíos viene la dirección de entrega y con un botón de desactivar. Con eso interpreto que esta activo. Me aparece como activo.

Comment: Pero tú generaste un código de envío [tal y como ellos te lo indican](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/)?

Comment: Yo tengo un modulo para MercadoEnvios muy vendido en Prestashop Addons, tengo muchos clientes con el mismo error, parece que van a quitar MercadoEnvios para Brasil y México, han ido desactivando los usuarios poco a poco, cada vez son menos lo que pueden usarlo fuera de MercadoLibre.

Comment: Cuando logran obtener soporte por algún método lo que le dicen es que no saben cuánto tiempo va durar, no hay fecha, no saben si va durar asi dias, semanas o meses. Creo que eso sonó a que mas nunca lo van activar.

Comment: Lo van a desactivar, y ya no podrán usarlo

Comment: van a desactivar que_?